# Is there a way to create a hash table without dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, hashmap, hashtable

**Question:**

I have a practice problem, where the input is a list of tuples of 5 integers, and the output is the number of similar tuples. For example, in [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (2, 3, 4, 5, 1), (1, 3, 2, 4, 5)], the output would be 2.

You're not supposed to use dictionaries though, but it is from CLRS, so you're meant to use the concept of hash tables.

---

**What I've tried so far:**

Some psuedocode I wrote below:

It goes through each index of the list, compares it to every other index and rotating it.

What I realized was wrong about this is, it would run in O(5n^2), which is too efficient for a book about algorithms. Any advice on what I can do to do this *without using a dictionary*?

```
def leftShift(tup, n):
    if not tup or not n:
        return tup
    n %= len(tup)
    return tup[n:] + tup[:n]

i = 0
t = 0
rotateTuple(L):
  while i < len(L):
    if L[i][i] in L[i+1]:
      while t < 4:
        .... //This is when I noticed it would fail
```

---

The output depends on the number of unique tuples in the list. A tuple is a duplicate if, when rotated by $n$, it is the same as another tuple in the list.

Comment: Why is the output `2`? What describes similarity? Where does a hash table actually fit into this?

Comment: @JonClements: I think he means equality. But then again what is the result for `[(1,2),(1,2),(2,3),(2,3),(2,3)]`?

Comment: That would be 2 since there are two unique tuples. @JonClements I edited the post. I'm supposed to use an implementation of a hash table, but not the built-in python dictionary. It's an odd restriction but a hashtable would allow for more comparison with less resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary *is* a hash table, so the only way to use a hash table without using a dictionary would be to implement your own, which I would not recommend.

You don't have to compare every tuple to every other tuple. Instead, you can "normalize" the tuples by rotating them such that the smallest element is in front, e.g. `3,2,6,9,4` would be rotated to `2,6,9,4,3`. If the list contains the minimum element more than once, you have to find all the positions of the minimum element and get the rotation that is "smallest" by natural order of lists, e.g. `1,2,3,4,1` is normalized to `1,1,2,3,4` and `1,3,1,2` to `1,2,1,3`.

```
def normalize(lst):
    min_ = min(lst)
    return min(lst[i:] + lst[:i] for i, e in enumerate(lst) if e == min_)
```

You could then just put the normalized tuples into a set of "unique" tuples in O(n).

```
lsts = [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (2, 3, 4, 5, 1), (1, 3, 2, 4, 5)]
unique = set(map(normalize, lsts))  # has length 2
```

It could be argued, though, that a `set` is just a `dict` with no values. In this case, you could sort the list of normalized tuples and check for duplicates in O(nlogn + n).

```
srtd = sorted(map(normalize, lsts))
n = len(lsts) - sum(srtd[i-1] == srtd[i] for i in range(1, len(srtd)))  # 2
```

Comment: The "key=lambda x" initializes a dictionary. Is there a way to get the same results without using dictionary. I'm going to try and implement your work using a linked list in the meantime.

Comment: @AndrewRaleigh I wasn't aware that the `key` parameter to `min` creates a `dict`; after all, each key is needed only once (other than e.g. the `key` for `sorted`). Anyway, see my edit for finding the `min` without `key` (and in fact without `min`).

Comment: Hey, I've noticed that it doesn't work for (3, 9, 15, 2, 1) and (15, 2, 1, 3, 9), any idea why not?

Comment: @AndrewRaleigh Can not reproduce, works fine for me. Are you sure those are actually all the same type, or maybe some `int`, some `float` or `str`?